# Pullback of algebraic cycles and homological triviality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cohomology, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety of dimension $2m$ for some $m \ge 2$ and $D$ be a non-singular divisor in $X$ such that the dual of the normal bundle of $D$ in $X$ is very ample. We have the natural Gysin map: $$ i^*: A^m(X) \to A^m(D)$$ Is it possible that there exists an algebraic cycle $\alpha \in A^m(X)$ not homologous to zero, $i^*(\alpha)$ is non-zero but homologous to zero? I am looking for examples when this happens. Any hint/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the condition on the normal bundle is not very restrictive: if you have such an example without the condition on the normal bundle then you can probably blow up a sufficiently ample divisor $E$ in $D$ to make the dual of the normal bundle of the strict transform of $D$ in the blow up very ample.

Comment: @naf: Are there examples without any restriction on the normal bundle of $D$ i.e., if we just assume $D$ is a non-singular divisor in $X$?

Comment: There are examples when $n=1$, and I suspect these can be adapted to the case of $n\geq 2$: blowup $\geq 10$ general points on a plane cubic, let $D$ be the strict transform of the plane cubic, and let $\alpha$ be the difference of two exceptional divisors.

Comment: There are easy examples: let $D$ be any variety with a cycle $\beta$ which is nonzero but homologous to $0$. Let $X = D \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and let $\alpha'$ be $\beta \times [\mathbb{P}^1]$. Then $\alpha'$ resticted to $D \times 0$ is $\beta$, but $\alpha'$ is homologous to $0$. Now let $\alpha$ be the sum of $\alpha$' and any cycle (of the appropriate dimension) in $D \times \{x\}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{P}^1$ which is not homologous to $0$.

Comment: @naf; Thanks for the example. This really helps.